# long running sp

Tags: sql, optimization

The following sp:
I have a stored procedure which runs anywhere from 1/2 minute to 4 hours (during nightly processing):

```
update tableA
set tableA.Other_Flag_50 = isnull(Staging.other_flag_50, 0)
from tableA
inner join (
    select acct_nbr,
        appl_code,
        Other_Flag_50
    from tableB
) Staging on tableA.lnhist_acct_nbr = Staging.acct_nbr
    and tableA.lnhist_appl_code = Staging.appl_code
```

I ran Blocking reports in Profiler for 2 nights in a row, first at 10 minutes interval then at 5 minutes. The stored procedure never shows up as being blocked (but it blocks other queries).

Any ideas on optimizing this? Would creating a view with the join help? (acct_nbr, appl_code, Other_Flag_50 from tableB) Thanks!!

Comment: Have you checked if the table has any indexes on it? Perhaps you need to add an index to improve this statement's performance.  Also have you checked the execution plan in for that update statement in SSMS (assuming you're using SQL Server)? It would tell you if a table scan, etc. is being done, and may help identify if/where an index is needed.

Comment: What database are you using?  I'm surprised this is doing what you expect, since TableA has the same alias in the update clause and the from clause.  I can't swear that SQL never supports this, but I don't usually mention the table name twice in an update query.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing the INNER JOIN directly to tableB?

```
UPDATE tableA 
SET tableA.Other_Flag_50=isnull(tableB.other_flag_50,0)
FROM  tableA 
INNER JOIN tableB
     ON tableA.lnhist_acct_nbr = tableB.acct_nbr 
     AND tableA.lnhist_appl_code = tableB.appl_code
```

Comment: I womder if that will lead to the same result... I will try it out and let you know. Thanks!!

Comment: This should not make any difference in recent SQLServer versions. The original form is unnecessarily complex, but functionally equivalent.

Comment: This doesn't work - it doesn't know what Staging is (Staging.other_flag_50).

Comment: I corrected the mistake. `Staging` needed to be replaced with the actual table name `tableB`.

Comment: Looks good, I believe it does the same. But both queries (old and new) execute in about 19s, which makes me wonder if it will change anything (even though it is cleaner code). In my mind, the big question continues to be how can this sp run for either 30-40s or 3-4 hours (that is the sp itself, not run in SSMS, parameter sniffing excluded). Is it possible the blocking report ran for 5 minutes update interval didn't catch some process that blocks it? I'm just afraid to run a report with an interval set to 10s over night. Is this a real possibility or should I forget blocking? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `rowlock` to prevent locking a whole table.

```
update tableA with (rowlock)
...
```

**EDIT**
Not sure about other RDBMS but the answer I provided works for SQL Server

Comment: I changed the query, modified indexes to span all columns retrieved, and that seemed to shave off a few seconds when it is run as a query in SSMS. However, it ran for (a record of) 5.8 hours last night. I know there are several reports running against that same table at the same time, so the only explanation is that this is holding it up. I will try with (rowlock) next.